# How to Add Required Billing Permissions using Google Cloud Project Factory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-billing

I am using the following terraform based on this modulehttps://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-project-factory:

```
module "project" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google"
  version = "~> 14.1"

  name                        = "project"
  random_project_id           = true
  org_id                      = var.organization_id
  billing_account             = var.billing_account
  default_service_account     = "deprivilege"
  budget_amount               = var.budget_amount
  budget_alert_spent_percents = var.budget_alert_spent_percents
  activate_apis = [
    "compute.googleapis.com",
    "dns.googleapis.com",
    "domains.googleapis.com",
    "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
    "billingbudgets.googleapis.com",
    "serviceusage.googleapis.com",
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how to add the required billing permissions using this module, and keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Error creating Budget: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
with module.project.module.budget.google_billing_budget.budget[0]
on .terraform/modules/project/modules/budget/main.tf line 41, in resource "google_billing_budget" "budget":
resource "google_billing_budget" "budget" {
```

No examples related to billing show anything additional that needs to be done apart from activating APIs. Before I manually add permissions, I would like to know how to do this with the module, or what permissions are required to add manually. Help would be greatly appreciated.

I have opened an issue about this here which references some permissions I think may be needed:
https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-project-factory/issues/789

Answer (score 2):

Only the users can create and manage Cloud budgets with a Billing Account Administrator role or a custom role with appropriate budget management permissions. This means that project owners without the Billing Account Admin role cannot create budgets for their respective projects.

It looks like there is a permissions issue. You need a role that includes the following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#permissions_required_for_this_task) on the Terraform Service Account:

1. billing.budgets.create to create a new budget.
2. billing.budgets.get and billing.budgets.list to view all budgets for the
   Cloud Billing account.

To gain these permissions, ask your administrator to grant you one of the following [Cloud Billing IAM](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access) roles on your Terraform Service Account:

- Billing Account Administrator
- Billing Account Costs Manager

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. I am aware of these permissions, they are mentioned in the issue I created. Where I am unsure is how to make sure the service account created with this module when a new project is defined has these permissions.